# How to draw a tag icon in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a tag like icon in canvas, but having a hard time doing the punch hole in the middle with no lines.

If possible, would like to make it like in the image, since here I tried with just basics shapes.
Image Example:
[image: tag icon]

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(100, 30, 150, 100);
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.translate(c.width/2,c.height/2);
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(0,0-100);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 3);
ctx.lineTo(0,0-100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="260" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a good start, we just needed to draw the circle with the `ctx.arc(` and use the `globalCompositeOperation` to cut out the hole to match your image.

On my example below I created a function that does the drawing of the tag, that way we can reuse to draw multiple tags

Improvements you could do later, maybe pass more parameters to have more control over how big is that triangle also the radius of the circle, and of course add color that is all up to you.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 1;

function drawTag(x, y, w, h) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);

  ctx.moveTo(x + w, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + w + w / 2, y + h / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  ctx.arc(x + w + w / 8, y + h / 2, h / 8, 0, 8, false)
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
}

drawTag(10, 10, 75, 50)

ctx.translate(140,50);
ctx.rotate(1);
drawTag(0, 0, 60, 40)

ctx.translate(40,60);
ctx.rotate(2);
drawTag(0, 0, 50, 30)
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I was also working on the circle part.
I had one question, what exactly is happening in the drawing of the circle `arc()`?

Comment: I know that `arc(x,y,r,sAngle,eAngle,counterclockwise)` as inputs, but the calculation part is little confusing for me.

Comment: Nothing special there... I tried different values until I got something I like, I suggest you do the same

Comment: Okay, will experiment with the inputs.

Comment: Yes that is the best way to learn ... you can also look for a mathematical approach to calculate the perfect center for that circle ... but personally I don't think is worth the time to research and code it, but it could be an interesting exercise

Comment: No need for GCO in this case, you can produce this shape with a single subpath: https://jsfiddle.net/mk4nufrz/ (Also `8` for `arc`'s endAngle ?o_O?)

Comment: @yong see the example above in comment from Kaiido, that is a nice alternative to using globalCompositeOperation

Comment: @Kaiido could you provide some information on why use single subpath? or could you add another answer with detail, would appreciate it.

Comment: Using a single subpath allows you to draw over a background without creating an hole on said background. GCO would: https://jsfiddle.net/zd53pbro/ vs https://jsfiddle.net/zd53pbro/1/ This offers you more flexibility in your drawings. But I'm not sure it's worth its own answer.

Comment: @Kaiido got what you're saying now, thanks.